# IIS 6 / Server 2003: Creating Subdomain for Mailserver

Tags: iis, smtp

What's the easiest way to create a subdomain for the mailserver (eg. mail.mydomain.com)
and connect it to the mailserver?

It should be possible when adding new domains that there's the mail-subdomain by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is done on your DNS server.  If you don't already have a DNS record for your mail server, then create an A (Host) record called 'mail' that has the IP address of your mail server.

Most mail software doesn't use host headers, but if it does then make sure to allow mail.mydomain.com on your mail server too so that your mail software is expecting that domain.

As for adding it for new domains, whatever you're using to create the zones now, add the A record automatically at that time.  Essentially it's at the DNS level where this is set.